# If and Else method between a jComboBox and 2 jTextFields

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, netbeans, methods

I've been trying to write a program that has two frames,the first one is NewJFrame and the second one is NewJFrame1, in the NewJFrame I've put a jComboBox (jComboBox1) and a jTextField (jTextField1) and a jButton(jButton1),in the second one i've put only a jTextField(jTextField2),
And I've written a code that should (when the jButton1 is clicked) take the chosen item from the jComboBox1 and put it into the jTextField 2 in the NewJFrame1 , now if the item  chosen in the jComboBox1 is "None" the printed text into the jTextField 2 should be what is written into the jTextField 1 in the NewJFrame,this button should also close the NewJFrame and open the NewJFrame1.Now when i tried to build the program it came back with 2 errors.These 2 errors are red lined by NetBeans,and when i looked at the suggestions it says:Cannot find symbol.
Thank you

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Object jTextField2;

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(159, 159, 159)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(54, 54, 54)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 151, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(80, 80, 80))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(95, 95, 95)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 99, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(63, 63, 63))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   NewJFrame1 a = new NewJFrame1();
   this.setVisible(false);
   a.setVisible(true);



   String Str;
   String Abc;

   Str = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
   Abc = jTextField1.getText().toString();


if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("None")){
 jTextField2.setText(Abc);/*****here is the error,it's the setText*****/
}
else 
{
jTextField2.setText(Str);/*****and here is the second error,it's the setText also*****/
}





}                                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

This is the output:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\\if combobox trial" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build    \built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build    \built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\build\generated-    sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox      trial\build\classes
C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\src\NewJFrame.java:108:     error: cannot find symbol
      jTextField2.setText(Abc);
  symbol:   method setText(String)
  location: variable jTextField2 of type Object
C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\src\NewJFrame.java:113:     error: cannot find symbol
jTextField2.setText(Str);    
      symbol:   method setText(String)
      location: variable jTextField2 of type Object
2 errors
C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\nbproject\build-impl.xml:945:     The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user\Documents\MYJAVAPROGRAMS\if combobox trial\nbproject\build-impl.xml:285:     Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: And... what happens? What are your inputs, what is your expected output, and what is your actual output?

Comment: Well I've assigned this code to a j Button, that button should open a new Frame and close the previous one and should print the text into the textfield that I've put in the new frame.
But when i try to build that application it comes back with 2 errors these two errors are red lined by netbeans it's the setText(both).

Comment: And when i check the suggestions it says :"Cannot find symbol"

Comment: OK. So the problem is that your code doesn't compile. Don't you think that your question should have this information? Show us the code that doesn't compile, show the exact and complete error messages you get from the compiler, and tell us which line of the posted code it refers to. And use the code button `{}` to format your code as code.

Comment: Anthony you need to make a better explanation about what is happening to you. We don't know *anything* about what are you trying to achieve. So please explain your problem from the beginning. What you just wrote makes sense to you because you know a lot more than we do about your problem. But read it as if you knew nothing and see how it's unclear. You have to explain: what are you trying to do, how are you trying to do it, why isn't it working and post the errors that occur.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that getSelectedItem does not return a string. Change it to

`if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("None")){`

Comment: Exceptions would be helpful. They help to identify the error. This kind of log file is difficult to read for people who use eclipse.

Comment: This code works if the jTextField2 is in the same Frame,
Do you think that if i create the 2 frames in a same package it would work ?

Comment: You need to have access to the jTextField. So you have to add it to the Frame you would like to use. Btw.: Please add imports. The code is really hard to read. Why would you like to create two JFrames/Frames? It would work, but I do not know why you need more than one. I only see one Frame in your code.

Comment: Pfft nah that is not the problem , but it seems that when the jTextField2 is not in the same frame the error"Cannot find symbol" of the setText method appears.. even when I've created a field for the jTextField2 in the NewJFrame.

Comment: i think the whole problem is that the jTextField2 is in another Frame  , but i already used "Private Object jTextField2" shouldn't that solve my problem ?

Comment: private Object jTextField2? Why do you use the Object class?

Comment: i though that would somehow introduce the jTextField2 from the second frame(NewJFrame2) to the first frame(NewJFrame).. excuse me if I'm such a rookie , but i really need to understand where i am going wrong.

Comment: JTextField is undefined for the type Object. You have to use private JTextField jTextField2. You did not instantiate the JTextField jTextField2. And the class NewJFrame1 does not exist. These are the errors shown in Eclipse.